# Spring WebFlow can I understand the previous state

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have a simple Spring WebFlow, which has a couple of states.

Is it possible when you reach a certain state to know which one was the previous one?

I need this because I want to detect when the user refresh the page, so in this case my previous state will be the same as my current state.

Comment: can you be more precise? are you talking about flows, or states within the same flow?

Comment: states within same flow, i want to able to understand from which state i am comming to the current one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set a variable like this:

```
<var name="comingFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>

<on-start>
    <set name="comingFrom" value="''"/>
<on-start>

<state id="state1">
    <transition on="transition1" to="current">
        <set name="comingFrom" value="'state1'"/>
    </transition>
</state>

<state id="current">
    /* do what you want in your state with "comingFrom" */
    <transition on="transistion2">
        <set name="comingFrom" value="'current'"/>
    </transition>
</state>
```

but that requires you set this variable on every transition that goes to your "current" state.

**[Edit] Example of decision-state:**

```
<decision-state id="decisionState">
    <if test="comginFrom != 'current'" then="state1" else="state2"/>
</decision-state>
```

Comment: is it possible to write something like if statement in "current" state to be able to understand what is the value of "comingFrom" variable and do specific transaction depending on value of "comingForm" variable

Comment: you can use a decision state and have an if statement in it

Comment: added a example of decision state